# how to open a file to Read and other to Write in C?

Tags: c, printf, fopen

Look this code

```
void readAndWrite() {
    char url[]="data.txt";
    char url2[]="output.txt";
    char data[256];
    FILE *arq;
    FILE *arqw;

    arq = fopen(url, "r");
    arqw = fopen(url2, "w");
    if(arq == NULL) {
        printf("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
    } else {
        while(fgets(data, 256, arq) != NULL) {         
            fprintf(arqw,"This %s",data);
        }
    }
    fclose(arq);
    fclose(arqw);
}
```

There is no problem opening the files. Both do not enter the NULL if. However, it is not possible to read the reading file.

Comment: Do you test that arqw is not NULL. Does the code execute successfully if you fprintf to stdout (or use printf) instead of writing to arqw?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that "data.txt" is created?
If it doesn't exist arg will be always NULL and you will get error open file.
Read about modificators https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm

You can read error what you have by errno
printf("errno is %d and fd is %d\n", errno, arq);

```
char url[] = "data.txt";
char url2[] = "output.txt";
char data[256];
FILE *arq;
FILE *arqw;

arq = fopen(url, "r");
if (arq == NULL) {
    printf("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
    printf("errno is %d and fd is %d\n", errno, arq);
}
else {
    arqw = fopen(url2, "w");
    while ((fgets(data, 256, arq)) != NULL) {
        fprintf(arqw, "This %s", data);
    }
    fclose(arq);
    fclose(arqw);
}
```

Comment: Yes. This file is created

Comment: Tutorialspoint is full of mistakes and frankly a horrible resource for learning C, even worse as a reference. Also, given the fact the op explicitly states they don't get the error, this is a comment at best. ( not trying to be shouty and I understand you cannot yet post comments but please don't abuse the answers section as a result :) )

Comment: Your code looks ok.  Do you need to use absolute paths?  Are the newlines in data.txt correct?